# Why angular.element commonly used without injection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

In Angular if people want to use some kind of library in their controllers/directives they use dependency injection like:

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    //stuff here
});
```

but I noticed that in case of `angular.element` - it is used just from global namespace:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    angular.element.find('body').html('Hello world!');
});
```

it is seem very strange to me, is it recommended practice?

Comment: Why does it seem more strange than using angular.directive in the preceding line?

Comment: @NewDev I used `app.directive`, not `angular.directive`

Comment: @GillBates Yes, but I believe the point he is making is that `app` came from `angular.module()`, so, it's no less strange.

Comment: @Brett But I use `angular` only once for instantiating module.

Comment: @GillBates Right, but, you didn't have to use dependency injection to use it. It's on the global scope.

Comment: @GillBates, not related to the question, but [some](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide) knowledgeable  [people](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#modules) recommend not using `var app = angular.module`, but always use `angular.module` as getter and setter.

Comment: @GillBates you wouldn't want to have to create a new jQuery object, just to use `$.extend` or `$.ajax`.  It wouldn't make sense to have to do `$(document).extend(obj, obj1, obj2)`, or require creating a jQuery plugin to do it.  These are core methods that are used by the actual framework/library, so they're included with the core library.  You also aren't going to inject `angular` into your `angular.module`. And for large projects, you use `angular` a lot more than just once.

Answer (score 1):

This is a helper method which exists on the actual `angular` framework, itself.

Much like `angular.extend`, `angular.module`, etc.

It would be very difficult to create a module, without referencing angular directly.
To that end, helper methods which are highly useful are extended onto `angular`, rather than requiring a third-party library.

That said, unless you are in a directive, or a very special-case service, you don't want to be using `angular.element`; while it's common, it's typically a holdover from someone used to working with jQuery, and a reluctance to figuring out a better way to architect a controller / widget / etc, so that Angular's data-binding does almost all of the DOM-work for you.